# Boolean logic --> Convert And to Or

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra

To convert an AND into an XOR, I can do:

```
AND(NOT(AND(A,B)), NOT(AND(NOT(A), NOT(B))))
```

$$\neg(A∧B)∧\neg (\neg A∧ \neg B)$$

How could I convert an `AND` into an `OR` with the constraint that I only use the `AND` and `NOT` logical operators?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Via [De Morgan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),

$$A \vee B = \neg(\neg A ∧ \neg B)$$

**Edit:** To be more explicit, using the De Morgan law $ \neg(p \vee q) = \neg p ∧ \neg q$, set $p = \neg A$, and $q = \neg B$. Note that $\neg p = A$, and $ \neg q = B$. Then, we get

$$A \vee B = \neg p \vee \neg q \overset{DM}= \neg (p ∧ q) = \neg (\neg A ∧ \neg B) $$

Or, if you prefer it without a change of varible,

$$ \neg(\neg A ∧ \neg B) = \neg((\neg A) ∧ (\neg B)) \overset{DM}= \neg(\neg A) \vee \neg(\neg B) = A \vee B$$

Comment: Thanks, could you show how you're able to flip negation? Normally I see deMorgan's as AND(NOT A, NOT B) = NOT(OR(A, B)). But you've basically flipped the NOT, so it's: NOT(AND(NOT A, NOT B) = OR(A,B). Could you please explain how that's valid to do?

Comment: I have edited to make everything explicit.